# Argument of type 'Pinia' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<[]>'

Tags: vue.js

I can't figure out what VueJS wants from me. I use typescript in the project.
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to connect Pinia to the VueJS project. Typescript swears.

I tried to make a plugin for the app, but it didn't help. In the documentation there is an opportunity to make a plugin with Pinia.

Pinia has a small community at the moment, so I haven't found an answer on the internet.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Also your packages are outadted if possible you should bootstrap a new project `npm init vue@latest`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `pinia` dependency.

Install pinia with this command `npm install pinia`

https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by removing the lock file (`yarn.lock`, `package-lock.json`, etc) and the `node_modules` folder and then reinstalling the dependencies.